# Automated R script through Task Scheduler not running complete script

Tags: r, automation, google-analytics, scheduled-tasks

I have an R script that I've set up to automatically update every week using Task Scheduler. The R script is supposed to pull out about 10 extracts from Google Analytics, however when I run the script through task scheduler it only extracts 4 and then seemingly stops. If I run it manually in RStudio it runs all the way through with no errors. Does anyone know why it might stop in Task Scheduler?

Comment: Did you check the errors in the log script?

Comment: I couldn't find any errors